# How to create a robust, minimal installer for Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I want to create an installer EXE with some specific properties:

1. it should be a single exe file
2. it should be robust (i.e. the technique should be known to work well on any Windows system)
3. it should create only a single file (a .scn screensaver file) in %systemroot%
4. it should add the option to uninstall that particular file in "Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs" but without creating any new entry `C:\Program Files` or copying an uninstaller.exe somewhere.

I've seen installers that work like that - so how to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be an EXE? Most Windows Installers are built as MSI (Microsoft Installer) now.. =)

Comment: If you do come up with a solution, be sure to send a copy to Microsoft. They haven't managed it yet.

Comment: ah well yeah - it meight be an MSI as well, as long as MSI installer files can be installed on any windows machines without prerequisites

Comment: The correct version of Windows Installer is a prerequisite for MSIs, but that should be on pretty any Windows system (and if it was missing most setups would fail).

Comment: Hmm... If it's only copying a single file around, and that file is a program anyway (scn screensavers are just renamed exe's), why not make that one program have three different modes? "run without parameters" == copy to %systemroot%, display dialog box "thanks for installing". run with parameter /s == display screensaver. run with parameter /u == uninstall (delete from %systemroot%).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you've said it can be an MSI, I'd suggest going down that route.

You could play around with installer projects in Visual Studio (if you have it; I'm not sure if the Express editions support making installers), as they'll quite happily produce an MSI that will do what you're asking. It's worth noting they'll produce an EXE and an MSI, you only need to distribute the MSI though.

Failing that, take a look at [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) as that will let you hand sculpt an MSI that does exactly what you want it to do and will cater for all five of your points above.

Note: Using an MSI will mean that you'll need to have Windows Installer on the machine you're installing to - It's in-box from Windows 2000/ME upwards.

Comment: No, the Express versions dont support making installers.

Comment: So i gave Visual Studio and the installer project a try, but the created MSI wants to create a Folder in the windows "Program Files" folder. I could not remove that from the installer since it told me that this is a required folder and cannot be removed :( So now i'm going to give NSIS a try...

Comment: WiX has been recommended by the Microsoft Windows Installer team - quite a recommendation. http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/12/595950.aspx

Comment: InnoSetup should be recommended before trying WiX (or anything else). It's so much simpler, involves practically no learning curve, is free even for commercial applications and doesn't leave anything to be desired imo

Answer (score 34):

Take a look at  [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) it is quite simple and it is used to create installers for Windows.

Comment: I found this GUI tool very helpful for the set up of my install script

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Script_Editor

Comment: For something this simple, NSIS is the best bet.

Comment: builtin script lang allow custom setups.

Comment: +1 because allow to create installers from a *nix (cross compiling from Linux, 2.51 is already present in Debian/unstable packages)

Answer (score 23):

I've heard good things about the free installer [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), and the website says it can create single EXE installs.

Comment: For start Inno Setup is better, because have an Wizard to make the setup file.

Comment: Innosetup is very easy, just copy the example file and add the name of your own exe. You don't need the pascal scripting unless you need to o something very complex

Comment: I've worked extensively with NSIS, tried IExpress, took a deeper look at WiX and have now tried InnoSetup. I must say the latter beats all other solutions by a long shot.

Comment: I tried Innosetup based on this answer, and I was able to get an installer in under an hour.  It took one or two more hours to figure out how to get my program to run after install, start on boot, and to copy files based on wildcards.  Overall, easy and flexible, I recommend.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), I think it can do all that you ask. I use it for slightly more complex installers but the free version is easy to use and powerful.

There can be an issue with MSI files, older PCs don't have the latest Windows Installer, 3.1, so you need to install that or prompt the user to, first! Have you looked into using [IExpress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx) if you just want to copy a file across?

Answer (score 5):

Both [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) and [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) will cope with all the tasks specified. Inno Setup uses a Pascal-like language for its scripts, NSIS uses its own script language.

Answer (score 4):

It come to my attention that this answer is still being read. This answer is over 5 years old and much of the information here may not be relevant anymore. Using IExpress also comes with its risks as well, which you can learn more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress#Security).

If you wish to proceed anyways, here is the old answer:

### <s>IExpress</s>

You can use Microsoft Windows's built in installer wizard called "Iexpress". To access that, open "Run", which is done by hitting Windows Key and R at the same time(WindowsKey+R). When you get in "Run", type in the little box "iexpress.exe". Then hit enter. You are there!

**Notes:** Only available on Microsoft Windows (Legit, and NonLegit)

***Setup Explained***:
**Page 1**

- Create a Self Extraction Directive file.
  Makes a new installation file
- Create a Self Extraction Directive file.
  Edits a `.SED` file
  **Page 2** (Of Create a Self Extraction Directive file.)
- Look in the "Description" at the bottom
  **Page 3**
- Package Title
  The name of your installer, as displayed at the top
  **Page 4**
- Confirmation Prompt
  What to tell the user before installing
  **Page 5**
- License Agreement
  Skip if you don't know what this is
  **Page 6**
- Packaged Files
  What files you need to install
  **Page 7**
- Show Window
  How the window is displayed
  **Page 8**
- Displayed At Top
  **Page 9**
- Package Names and Options
  Where to save your File
- Hide File Extracting Progress From User
  Hides the animation
- Store File using Long Name inside installer
  Ignore if you don't know what this is
  **Page 10**
- Displayed At Top
  You are done!
  Click on the Title to download the file, without doing those instructions. If it is a virus, got infected or you think it is a virus, feel free to delete the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single installer file using just Visual Studio 2017 Pro and Windows in 3 steps:

1. To have an entry in the Add/Remove Programs, you need to have a
   setup project.
2. The setup project may compile into 2 files: *.msi and
   setup.exe
3. To create a self-extracting package, you can use the
   IExpress tool

Comment: Just what I need. Thanks

Comment: I think this answer would be even better if you could post some more details of it here, instead of linking to that video on Youtube. You see, links to external websites can always become invalid (Youtube won't close down, but they could remove the video, for example), and without that video this answer wouldn't really help much. So please [edit] it and add something more. Besides, compared to text, videos aren't great for usability (you can't search their content, you can't print them, they require a couple of minutes instead of a few seconds for a quick scan...). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your heartfelt comment. I wish that StackOverflow has a feature to host tutorial videos so that we don't have to host it on another platform.

Answer (score 1):

NSIS, MSI any installer can do that for you.

NSIS is pretty small and compact.

Answer (score 1):

The **not copying an installer somewhere** and **adding an entry into Add/Remove** seem to be counteractive.  My understanding is that add-remove programs neccesarily references a copy of the uninstaller that resides in a Windows directory (so it doesn't lose access to it).

Perhaps you could have the screensaver double as an uninstaller if you pass it some sort of command-line option. Then simply tell the msi that the uninstaller IS the screensaver (hence no unnecessary coping to some other directory.)

Comment: With an MSI, Windows caches it in %windir%\installer anyway, so it doesn't create any files in %programfiles% or anywhere else, which I guess probably satisfies the spirit of point 5, if not the exact wording =)

Comment: it seemed very specific "or not coping uninstaller somewhere"... cacheing vs coping?

Comment: caching is actually fine if that chache folder is hidden from the user anyway

Answer (score 1):

NSIS is the way to go, very simple to learn, just write a simple file specifying which files you want to install over where. You can also add QuickLaunch options and so on. Then run the NSIS compiler and you get the exe.

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield has a release option called "Single .EXE".  It can bundle the payload inside, plug register w/Add-Remove Programs as you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [CQtDeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer) tool. This tool using the [Qt Installer Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) for create installers and supports Windows and Linux platforms.

1. Install the [cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases) tool. I am recommended use the online installer, because it has the latest version of cqtdeployer with minor bug fixes.
2. Open the cmd with your framework envirement.
3. Run the cqtdeployer for your application on the cmd.

```
cqtdeployer -bin path\to\myApp.exe qif
```

If you use Qt then add the qmake option.

```
cqtdeployer -bin path\to\myApp.exe -qmake path\to\qmake.exe qif
```

For more examples of using this util see the CQtDeployer [Wiki](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/wiki/quickguide)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use standard deployment methods with your installer you probably should stay away from NSIS.  See http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project. It is pretty easy to use.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

You can install it as an extension in visual studio.