# how to create folder in %windir%/installer/{.....} from visual studio 2008 installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, icons

This question is related to my question about how to create a clean minimal setup here:
[How to create a robust, minimal installer for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074013/how-to-create-a-robust-minimal-installer-for-windows)

I managed to create a simple msi installer in visual studio 2008 that does nothing else than installing a .scn file into %systemroot% and it also adds an option to "Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs". To provide the uninstall functionality, it automatically caches an msi file in %windir%/installer

The only problem left i have is that i'd like to use my custom icon (which i also use as icon for the .scn file) for the display within "Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs". Visual Studio has the option to chose the "AddRemoveProgramsIcon", but it allows only to use .ico files that get actually copied to the destination computer.

I have found in the %windir%/installer folder a lot of folders with names like {FDD8070F-E3B9-0409-822C-CCFE5E82C14D} and many of them simply contain an icon file, so i guess it's exactly what i need to do - to create such a folder there and copy my icon into it.

My question is, what is the right way to create this folder (from within a Visual Studio 2008 Installer Project)? Should i use "add userdefined folder" and name it by hand, or is there a correct automatical way to create this folder? (such that for example if i update the product code of my project, that automatically also the name of this folder is adapted)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom installer class by following the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx

Then during the Install method you could 'simply' create a folder in the Windows directory by using the variables of the Environment class.

I can't comment on whether or not adding the folder and icon there will solve your problem, but I'm pretty sure you could create the folder you want using this method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click Installer Project
2. View --> File System (on Target Machine)
3. Right Click Application Folder-->Add-->Folder-->Rename Folder
4. Right Click new Folder Created-->Add-->File-->Select Multiple Files
5. Rebuild Setup Project

:) Happy Coding----------