# Python files to an MSI Windows installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, executable, pyinstaller

So I can use PyInstaller to make a one-file executable and to make a standard executable among other files in a folder.

But how do I turn Python files into an MSI installer so that it's fool-proof where it makes a shortcut on the desktop? **(For distribution so that it isn't required for the user to have Python installed)**

*(When I say Python files to an MSI installer I mean the regular PyInstaller to folder output but with a way of getting a shortcut to the executable onto the desktop very easily for a regular user)
**(It doesn't have to be PyInstaller if there's an alternative).***

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219045/windows-run-python-command-from-clickable-icon

Comment: I'm trying to do it as an executable. So that it doesn't require Python to be installed. I'm not asking how to make a shortcut, I'm asking how to turn Python files into an installer that can be launched by anyone + It should create a shortcut on the desktop automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyinstaller does not intergrate such a tool.

You could get a third party installer (some suggested here [How to create a robust, minimal installer for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074013/how-to-create-a-robust-minimal-installer-for-windows)) and add your output exe to it and install that way, if you choose the right tool you will be able to add to desktop (plus a lot of other actions such as adding to path ect).

Or you could use cx_Freeze which has it built in.  When running the setup script just add the [`bdist_msi`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#bdist-msi) flag.

It can add to shortcut desktop but is fairly limited in other ways (or you may need to perform some hack).

To add to desktop with cx_Freeze see [Use cx-freeze to create an msi that adds a shortcut to the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734703/use-cx-freeze-to-create-an-msi-that-adds-a-shortcut-to-the-desktop).

Comment: cx_freeze is just bad. I've been tinkering with it for a decade, lack of documentation and many unanswered questions here on StackOverflow. i suggest you do not plan anything serious like big project relay on it

Comment: @AbdullahSaid I honestly have used it a ton.  Whenever I need to convert Python I use CX_Freeze.  Then again I know the Python file system extremely well, so I can tinker around with the setup script until it's working.  My main reason for using it, is that it's maintained.  Unlike most of the alternatives

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Inno* which creates a shortcut on the desktop and start menu. Also, it is located in the program directory of windows. it means that you can install/uninstall it like other programs or applications.

- Inno website:
  https://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php
- A tutorial on how to use it on youtube:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTQ-atboQiI

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php).
It's a **simple** and **robust** tool that can make your portable exe file into a **Windows Installer** setup file.

Very simple to use and has a lot of features, like the option to automatically create **desktop shortcuts**, paths, folders, etc.

Here is an example, on my GitHub with detailed documentation from **Python script to EXE to Windows installer file**.

-> My Github [Example](https://github.com/Abhijeetbyte/Python-Script-to-Application)