# How to convert python file to installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-installer, installation, exe

Hi everyone I want to convert my python file to `installer`(windows installer) not `executable`. I already make it `executable` through `py2exe`. How can I make an Installer of it. Is it possible.

Comment: take a look on this project https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python files to an MSI Windows installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879667/python-files-to-an-msi-windows-installer)

Comment: https://cyrille.rossant.net/create-a-standalone-windows-installer-for-your-python-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyinstaller is a good option to convert python scripts to an windows executable.
You can install it in `cmd.exe` as any user and run `pip install pyinstaller` or `pip install --pre pyinstaller`.

you can then run it using `pyinstaller`. (sorry that i can't supply a automated script i wrote after a system restore. I'll write it again soon using pyqt5)

#### syntax

> `--onefile` - puts the program and it's files into a exe.
>
> `--onedir` - put your program into a directory (folder) (faster than `--onefile` as it does not need to extract files)
>
> `-c` - create a console app.
>
> `-w` - create an app without the console.
>
> `-i "[Path to .ico or exe with icon. e.g C:\Files\CODE\Icon.ico]"` - set an icon for your app instead of the default snake-on-a-floppy-disk icon.

you can read the rest [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

You can then get [inno setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) and create an offline installer.

[sorry, could not be bothered to type it again]
i posted it on https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61597594